# Mean squared error derivation question

Tags: statistics, regression

$\text{MSE} = \operatorname E_y \operatorname E_x[y - x'\gamma]^2$ which can be written:

$$\text{MSE} = \operatorname E_{y,x}\{[y - \operatorname E[y\mid x])\}^2 +  \operatorname E_{y, x}\{\operatorname E[y\mid x]- x'\gamma\}^2$$

where $x$ is a vector of independent variables in the population regression.

Why can the first expression be written as the second? I assume they have added and subtracted a constant $\operatorname E(y\mid x)$.

If so, where did the cross terms go?

Comment: I'm really puzzled by the seeming universality of spelling "where" with a capital initial "w" in this context. Can you explain why that's done?

Comment: It might be automatic.  Because of the preceding new line, the software assumes a new sentence.  I find that I need to override its behaviour in this context.

Comment: $\newcommand{\e}{\operatorname{E}}$This practice of putting subscripts on the expectation operator is an error, and its erroneous nature has been the topic of a question posted here. However, I will take you use of that operator with a subscript $x$ to indicate you're treating $x$ as random rather than constant.

So you have $\e(( y -x'\gamma)^2),$ where I take $y$ to be a scalar-valued random variable and $x$ to be a random vector, and $\gamma$ to be a constant vector (i.e. not random). Then you write$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: \begin{align}
& \e\Big( \big( (y - \e(y\mid x)) + (\e(y\mid x) - x'\gamma) \big)^2\Big) \\ \\
= {} & \e\Big((y-\e(y\mid x))^2\Big) + 2\underbrace{\e\Big((y-\e(y\mid x))(\e(y\mid x) - x'\gamma)\Big)} + \e\Big((\e(y\mid x) - x'\gamma)^2\Big)
\end{align}
So the question is: Why is the expected value that appears over the $\underbrace{\text{underbrace}}$ equal to $0\text{ ?}$ (The random variable inside the $\Big(\text{big parentheses}\Big)$ is not constantly $0;$ indeed it's probably nonzero with probability $1$.) $\qquad$

Comment: @badjohn : If it's automatic, why have I never seen it happening to me? $\qquad$

Comment: I don't recall capitalizing the W in 'where', but i will keep in mind it should begin without capitalization in future. The expression is copied from Greene's Econometric Analysis 7E page 53. I'm not certain what the author means by the subscripts; I assumed it was an expectation conditional on both y and the vector x.

Comment: Different browser or O/S?  I am not suggesting that the behaviour is controlled by the site.  I am used to seeing automatic capitalisation after a new line whether or not the preceding text ended with a full stop (period).

Comment: The text says the subscript notation is 'the expectation over the values of x'. What does 'expectation (of an arbitrary variable) over the values of x' mean?

Comment: ok, Now I suspect maybe $\gamma$ was not intended to be constant, but is the least-squares estimate that depends on the random vector $x$ and the random scalar $y. \qquad$

Comment: @MHall : That is abominable notation.

Comment: @MHall : I wonder if you can confirm or deny my suspicion expressed two comments above this, about what $\gamma$ is intended to be?

Comment: Yes, I can, you are correct. $\gamma$ is to be chosen to minimize the mean squared error. I think x is taken to be non-stochastic here but y is stochastic through the regression error term $\epsilon$. I'm not sure is $\gamma$ random or not in this context. In the solution $\gamma$ will be equal to the regression's $\beta$, showing that OLS $\beta$ is minimum squared error linear predictor of actual slopes $\beta$.